# Confusion Regarding overflows in Java

Tags: java, c++, c

I have the following statement:

```
long result = a * b * c;
```

This causes an overflow in the variable result. And so does:

```
long result = (long)a * b * c;
```

But the when broken down, they don't:

```
long result = a;
result *= b;
result *= c;
```

The type of a and b is `int`.

Can someone please explain why this is so? Does Java store the intermediate results in a temporary internal int variable in the first two cases?

Also do C and C++ behave the same way?

Comment: What types are `a`, `b`, and `c`? `int`s?

Comment: please don't use so many `<br>` tags; it's hard to fix your formatting when they're there.

Comment: Yes, a, b, c are ints

Comment: @Doorknob ok. Will keep that in mind next time. :)

Comment: I do not get the same results with snippet you provided.  It builds, runs and gives expected result.  Of course I am assuming you have initialized a, b & c to some reasonable value?

Comment: If a, b & c are each initialized to to 2,147,483,000, then you will have problems.

Comment: It's stupid to dork with this -- there are too many "gotchas".  Just assign all 3 to `long` temps and be done with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming `a * b * c` fits in a `long`, but `a * b` does not fit in an `int` -

- Your first snippet gives an overflow because `a * b` goes into a temporary `int`, as you suspected.
- Your second snippet does NOT give an overflow, as you claim, because it is multiplying `long` values at each point.
- Your third snippet doesn't give an overflow, because it is also multiplying `long` values at each point.

And, yes, C and C++ both work this way too; although depending on the platform, they may have different lengths for both `int` and `long`.

Answer (score 2):

See the [Oracle documentation for operator precedence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

Unary has higher precedence than multiplication, so `(long)a*b*c` is `(long)(a)*b*c`.

Same in [C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

I just tested these programs:

```
public class JavaApplication2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long l = (long)Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        l *= 2;
        l *= 2;
        System.out.println(l);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class JavaApplication2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long l = (long)Integer.MAX_VALUE*2*2;
        System.out.println(l);
    }
}
```

They show the exact same output.

In contrast, remove the cast in the second version and you get an overflow.